# What type of knife is this?

Tags: knives

My brother found it in a box in his storage.  It goes back years to a pack and move.  It probably belonged to my father, who wasn't a professional chef, but he was a very knowledgeable hobbyist who knew a few professional chefs.  I was told, growing up that he took classes from James Beard at one time.   It almost looks like a broken steak knife, but the top of the blade is smooth and tapered.  This is the original shape.

[image]

Comment: It's possible that it's not a culinary knife at all.  If I saw that out of context, I'd assume that it was something for woodworking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possibly a fish scaler.

A google search for PAL RH22 turned up just one result, with a picture of the same knife [plus sheath] & only one answer as to what it is.
https://www.allaboutpocketknives.com/knife_forum/viewtopic.php?t=19079

Comment: Your link led me to this.    R.M.L. fish knife.

https://www.gunauction.com/buy/12457430/  

and

https://www.antiquesnavigator.com/d-148258/antique-rml-trout-fish-filet-knife-tackle-box-knives.html   For filleting small fish.   Close enough.